# getting lots of package dependencies while installing wine on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

i have tried the instructions from here:

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

steps:
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
`sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings`
`sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key`
`sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources`
`sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

but i get this:
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:`
`winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 8.0.0.0~jammy-1)`

and when i try installing `wine-stable`, i get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
apt : Depends: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.9) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
bsdutils : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
libdbus-1-3 : Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
           Recommends: dbus
libpci3 : Depends: libudev1 (>= 196) but it is not installable
libpulse0 : Depends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
libusb-1.0-0 : Depends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable
shim-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not going to be installed or
                    grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) but it is not installable
           Depends: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24)
util-linux : PreDepends: libsystemd0 but it is not installable
          PreDepends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable
wine-stable-amd64 : Depends: libudev1 (>= 183) but it is not installable
```

i tried ti install the dependencies, but i have all of them installed. i'm totally condused! how can i install wine really?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, you are missing `sudo apt update` before `... apt install ...` . Have you run it?

Comment: yes, i forgot to mention that. thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 2):

You are merely the latest of many who have been led astray by those winehq instructions. Please let them know that their documentation has frustrated yet another user.

The easy way to install Wine:

1. Undo EVERYTHING that those instructions told you to install. Every package. Every script. Every apt source. Even the architecture.

   This is the hard part. Be methodical. If it's a new system, it might be easier to reinstall. You cannot leave ANY winehq detritus behind; it creates version conflicts that prevent anything else from being installed.
2. Once you have returned your Ubuntu system to stock condition, simply `sudo apt install wine`

   Wine, along with a lot of other great software, has been in the Ubuntu repositories for nearly two decades. Get out of the habit of going to random websites for software; that's how you break your system. Go to your Ubuntu Software application instead. Just about everything that most users need is already there.